# RegEx: Separating a String in two at the $

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a string that I import into my javascript application. It consists of this:

> Text here (some text in parenthesis) $Price

I would like to separate this string into three strings (The beginning part, the parenthesis, and the price).

I know this probably involves regular expressions, but that is a beast I cannot hope to tackle right now. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Without regular expressions, this works:

```
var part1 = mystring.substring(0, mystring.indexOf('('));
var part2 = mystring.substring(mystring.indexOf('(') + 1, mystring.indexOf(')'));
var part3 = '$' + mystring.split('$')[1];
```

Example/demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/fallen888/6EU3W/3/

***Update***:

```
var part1 = null;
var part2 = null;
var part3 = null;

if (mystring.indexOf('(') >= 0 && mystring.indexOf('(') > 0) {
    part1 = mystring.substring(0, mystring.indexOf('('));
    part2 = mystring.substring(mystring.indexOf('(') + 1, mystring.indexOf(')'));
    part3 = '$' + mystring.split('$')[1];
}
else {
    var parts = mystring.split('$');
    part1 = parts[0];
    part2 = '$' + parts[1];
}
```

Comment: These are all great! But what if there is no parenthesis component and I want to skip that middle one when there isn't or put in a value of null? Do I just do an if statement?

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "Text here (some text in parenthesis) $33.55";
var matches = str.match(/(.+) (\(.+\)) (\$.+)/);
```

Gives you:

```
["Text here (some text in parenthesis) $33.55", "Text here", "(some text in parenthesis)", "$33.55"]
```

`matches[1]`, `matches[2]`, and `matches[3]` contain what you want.

Comment: This is perfect and it has regex! Will this work though if, say, there is no text in parenthesis? It's not guaranteed right now that there will be parenthesis at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just change the `(\(.+\))` to `(\(.*\))`. Now the `.` will match 0 or more times so it will match situations where there is no text in the parentheses. If you want it to match even if there are no parentheses, then you can do change it to `(\(.*\))?`, which matches that whole capturing group 0 or 1 times. So this handles the case where you might not have the parenthesized text.

Answer (score 1):

```
var match = "Text here (some text in parenthesis) $Price".match(/(.+)(\(.+\))(.+)/);
match[1], match[2], match[3];
```

Or using `split` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var split12 = "Text here (some text in parenthesis) $Price".split('(');
var split1 = split12[0];
var split23 = split12[1].split(')');
var split2 = '(' + split23[0] + ')';
var split3 = split23[1];
```

Better to learn some regexp, don't you think?

http://jsfiddle.net/K9Cxe/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

([\w\s]+) (([\w\s]+)) (\$\w+)

Assuming that when you say text, it is alpahnumeric. If you want to allow punctuation marks, modify `[\w\s]` to include those as well. (e.g. to include comma -> `[\w\s,]`).